# how to display php microtime as min: sec?

Tags: php

I display the code execution time in seconds using:

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
// code here
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = ($time_end - $time_start);
$time = number_format((float)$time, 3, '.', '');
echo "Process Time: {$time} sec";
```

I got for example:

```
9.809 sec
```

I want to display the execution as:
`min : sec` , with sec unit if the min <1 and min unit if min >1.
I have no issue do the unit job but, microtime gives the time in millisecond how can I get the previous output as:

```
00:09 sec or 03:50 min
```

**Solution:**
either:

```
date('i:s', (int) $time);
```

or:

```
$minutes = floor($time / 60);
$seconds = $time % 60;

$minutes = str_pad($minutes, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$seconds = str_pad($seconds, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

echo "Process Time: $minutes:$seconds";
```

Thanks all

Comment: So 9 seconds should print out as "00:09" and 230 seconds should print out as "03:50"?

Comment: @maxhb exactly like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a solution without using a date-formatter - doing it all by yourself:

```
$minutes = floor($time / 60);
$seconds = $time % 60;

$minutes = str_pad($minutes, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$seconds = str_pad($seconds, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

echo "Process Time: $minutes:$seconds";
```

**note:** this also works if minutes are equal to or greater than 60. even if your minutes are greater than 99. the latter will need more than two spaces tho (outputs `120:00` for 2 hours for example).

Answer (score 4):

You should use a little helper function:

```
<?php
$times = array(9.123, 230.455, 3601.123);

foreach($times as $time) {
  echo $time . " => " . formatMicrotime($time) . "\n";
}

function formatMicrotime($time) {
   return date('i:s', (int) $time);
}
```

Output is:

```
9.123 => 00:09
230.455 => 03:50
3601.123 => 00:01
```

As you can see, you'll get into trouble if the time span is larger than 1 hour, but that's probably not an issue if you are measuring execution times of your script ;-)

Comment: I am test it now. Anyway, low_rents's solution solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. This is another solution